# Styled-components - dynamic CSS?

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

I have a simple React app that gets CSS from an external source in JSON form, the styles look like this:

```
{
  "DOMElements": [
    {
      "padding": "1rem",
      "margin": "5rem",
    },
    {
      "boxSizing": "border-box",
      "height": "10px",
    }
  ]
}
```

So when I get a response like above I want end up with something like this:

```
import styled from 'styled-components';

const DOMElement1 = styled.div`
   padding: 1rem,
   margin: 5rem,
`;

const DOMElement2 = styled.div`
   boxSizing: border-box,
   height: 10px,
`;

const Page = ({ children }) => (
  <>
    <DOMElement1>{children[1]}</DOMElement1>
    <DOMElement2>{childrem[2]}</DOMElement2>
  </>
);
```

It's worth noting that number of DOMElements in unknown, it might be 1, it might be 50.

The component part is easy, I can do just do `indexed map` and increase index every loop.
The problem I face is - how do I create dynamic styled-components props based on JSON response? I need to do it within the component itself as that's where I know how `DOMElements` look like, but styled-components are supposed to be outside of the component function... What am I missing? Is it even doable?

Answer (score 0):

You can give props for styled components.

```
const DOMElement1 = styled.div`
   padding: ${({padding}) => padding}rem,
   margin: ${({margin}) => margin}rem,
`;

const Page = ({ children }) => (
  <>
    <DOMElement1 padding={valueFromJson} margin={valueFromJson}>{children[1]}</DOMElement1>
    <DOMElement2 padding={valueFromJson} margin={valueFromJson}>{childrem[2]}</DOMElement2>
  </>
);
```

Comment: I'm aware of that, the problem is I won't have two DOM elements, their number will be dynamic/unknown, this was just an example. I'd use `children.map` instead of hardcoding `DOMElements` like in the code above.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
const items = [
  {
    background: "blue",
    width: "30px",
    height: "30px",
    padding:'10px'
  },
  {
    height: "40px",
    background: "red",
    width: "30px",
    padding:'10px'
  }
];

const components = items.map((item) =>
  styled("div")({
    ...item
  })
);

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div style={{ background: "lightblue", width: "100vw", height: "100vh" }}>
      {components.map(Comp => <Comp>hi</Comp>)}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: `items` will be sent as props to `App`, therefore I can't access them outside of the `App` component :[

Comment: You can do it inside: 
`return items.map((item) =>
  styled("div")({
    ...item
  })
).map(C => <C />) }
`

Answer (score 0):

A simple & straightforward solution would be **taking props dynamically in your styled component** and this way you don't need to worry about any incoming css property.

Refer the following example/ [**this**](https://codesandbox.io/s/angry-snowflake-xtuy8) snippet -

```
const DOMElement = styled.div`
   ${props => props}
`;

const Page = () => {
  const data = {
    "DOMElements": [
      {
        "padding": "1rem",
        "margin": "5rem",
      },
      {
        "boxSizing": "border-box",
        "height": "10px",
      }
    ]
  };

  return (
    <>
     {data?.DOMElements?.map((obj, index) => 
        <DOMElement {...obj} key={index}>abcd</DOMElement>
      )}
    </>
  );
}
```

**Output snap -**
[image: loading output snap]